# Single SSL certificate over multiple servers to send Push notifications to same application

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to use single SSL certificate over multiple servers to send Push notifications to same application.We have Client and Server, client will be downloaded from appstore where as server will will be installed by individual customer on their own network. For all customers client application is same, we cannot submit the individual app for every customer. So, is there any limitation by apple on this scenario.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such kind of limitation by APPLE. **What APPLE care is push notification is to be sent by proper connection and certificate.**

And there is no any documented limit available as of now, so shouldn't be a case, [Check This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374135/any-limitation-push-notification-via-apns-or-c2dm) for more confirmation to this assurance as that user has sent 7 million of push notifications with different servers in a month as he has claimed.

Comment: Welcome. We are here to help and get helped.

Comment: @JanakNirmal I am trying to send apple pushnotification from PHP. I am a newbe to this.. My doubt is we must enable SSL certificate in my server to send pushnotification in iOS ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use multiple SSL certificates to send push notifications from multiple servers to the same application. This has been made possible by Apple only recently. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365302/is-it-possible-to-create-multiple-ssl-certificates-for-providers-that-send-apns/15902579#15902579) for more details.